# How to fix Errors when adding Check function: 3815 or 3814. An expression of a check constraint contains disallowed function

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I have a problem with MYSQL. I have one table "screening" that consist of scrreningID(PK), movieID (FK) and roomID (FK). I want to make a check that if the  movie is3d and room canplay3d, insert function can be executed. Otherwise, if movie is not3d and the room canplay3d then the insert cannot be done.

I try to alter my tabla and add a Check constraint. I created a Function for the Check constraint. However, It is always getting Error

Here is my function Code :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `is3d`(mov int, roo int) RETURNS int(11)
    READS SQL DATA
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
declare movie_3d integer;
declare room_3d integer;

select is3d into movie_3d from movie where movieID = mov; 
select canplay3d into room_3d from room_auditorium where roomID = roo;

if (movie_3d = 1 && room_3d =1) then
RETURN 1;
else
return 0;
end if;

END
```

The function is successful and it works well. But when I add it to the Check constraint

```
alterter table screening_show add constraint 
checkisthreedy check (is3d(movieID, roomID) = 1)
```

it always shows an error:

Error Code: 3814. An expression of a check constraint xonstrainname contains disallowed function: `CustomerLevel`.

I also tried to make basic functions, but the result is still the same when I use it for Check constraint.

Comment: You cannot use functions in check constraints https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and when I checked the MYSQL user manual I found this.

CHECK condition expressions must adhere to the following rules. An error occurs if an expression contains disallowed constructs.

1. Stored functions and user-defined functions are not permitted.
2. Stored procedure and function parameters are not permitted.

You can refer more about the check constraint at [THIS LINK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html)

Comment: did you find a solution around it or is this the end of it

Answer (score 0):

The only way to solve this I see is calling the function manually like this:

```
insert into table_name (a, b, с)
select 1, 2, 3
where is3d(1, 1) = 1
```